# 2's complement subtraction conversion to decimal

Tags: math, binary, subtraction

I was having some problem when trying to perform a 2's complement subtraction. So the question is:

```
  01110101
- 11010110
----------
```

Then I perform the following to get the answer:

```
  01110101 (+ve) -> I convert to decimal I get (+117)
- 00101010 (-ve) -> I convert to decimal I get (-42)
----------
  10011111 (-ve) -> I convert to 01100001 and get (-97)
```

However, 117-(-42) = 159. I wonder which part went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The part where the answer is larger than can fit in the space given. A signed 8-bit integer can only hold values between -128 and 127 inclusive, so the result of the operation will be incorrect.

Comment: Alright but then how do I convert it to decimal for checking? I got confusion by converting them.

Comment: You will need to temporarily use a larger datatype, e.g. an unsigned 10-bit integer.